# How can eclipseLink profiler output to log4j but not stdout

Tags: java, jpa, jboss, eclipselink

I enable the eclipselink profiler by setting

The information is printed in stdout. 
Could I change it to log4j and then log it with level level and package name?

Because I would like to switch off the logging by config in jboss.

Comment: have you tried changing any of the logging settings?  https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging

Comment: Yes. I used custom logger to log generated sql.